# sandboxed iframe with local scoped cookies only

Tags: javascript, security, cookies, iframe, sandbox

Is it possible to load a sanboxed iframe that can run scripts and write cookies but they don't overwrite the parent's cookies?

For example outer HTML will look like this:

**outer.html**

```
  <html>
   .....
    <script>document.cookie='page=outer; path=/';</script>
    <iframe sandbox="<attribute-here>"  src="./inner.html"></iframe> 
   .....
  </html>
```

**inner.html**

```
  <html>
   .....
    <script>document.cookie='page=inner; path=/';</script>
   .....
  </html>
```

The desired result is that the outer page always remains with the cookie value `outer` and the inner one has the value `inner`